# Adding dependencies in Maven Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, maven, jar, dependencies, jmf

I've created a Maven project and added the dependencies (jar files) that I need; however, netbeans says that it still cannot find it.

Specifically in my case, I added the jmf-2.1.1e.jar file into my dependencies folder. When I go back to my program it still gives me the compile error that it cannot find the javax.media package.

Answer (score 17):

Did you let Netbeans manage the dependency?

In your "Projects" listing, find and context+click on the "Dependencies" folder in the list. From the context menu, choose "Add Dependency".

[image: screen shot of Projects listing with context menu of Dependencies folder]

This approach works at least in NetBeans 7.4 and 8.0 beta.

Comment: Does this menu allow to add dependency from file?

Comment: @zygimantus If you mean adding a local copy of a library to your project, No. That is not a “dependency” which means letting a software tool like Maven do the work on your behalf to locate on the Internet a source for the desired library, download, and install it within your project. You can manually add a library yourself, but doing so does not involve a “dependency manager” such as Maven. See [introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) on Maven site.

Comment: In Maven fantasy world it's "not a dependency", but in real life it's a project dependency. Maven is stupid.

Comment: How do you make the **Dependencies** node appear; so i may right-click it to add a dependancy?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your `pom.xml` has the following snippet that defines the dependency

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1e</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: The  **<dependency></dependency>**  tag must be within  **<dependencies></dependencies>**  tag .

Answer (score 2):

The dependency is available in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.media|jmf|2.1.1e|jar). Add the pom snippet manually to the pom.xml and run Maven in the shell and let it download the dependency. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maven automatically downloads the dependency once specified in the pom.xml.  For this you would have to build your project with the dependency as specified by Tim Sparg.