# How do I set the classpath in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

Can someone tell me where and how I set the classpath in NetBeans? I would like to add a .jar file.

Comment: Note that none of the currently posted answers answer the actual question asked by OP.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

1. Right-click your Project.
2. Select `Properties`.
3. On the left-hand side click `Libraries`.
4. Under `Compile tab` - click `Add Jar/Folder` button.

Or

1. Expand your Project.
2. Right-click `Libraries`.
3. Select `Add Jar/Folder`.

Answer (score 14):

## Maven

The [Answer by Bhesh Gurung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598688/642706) is correct… unless your NetBeans project is [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) based.

### Dependency

Under Maven, you add a "dependency". A dependency is a description of a library (its name & version number) you want to use from your code.

Or a dependency could be a description of a library which another library needs ("depends on"). Maven automatically handles this chain, libraries that need other libraries that then need other libraries and so on. For the mathematical-minded, perhaps the phrase "Maven resolves the transitive dependencies" makes sense.

### Repository

Maven gets this related-ness information, and the libraries themselves from a [Maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). A repository is basically an online database and collection of download files (the dependency library).

## Easy to Use

Adding a dependency to a Maven-based project is really quite easy. That is the whole point to Maven, to make managing dependent libraries easy and to make building them into your project easy. To get started with adding a dependency, see this Question, [Adding dependencies in Maven Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6819317/642706) and [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493665/642706) with [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHBDP.png).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, the actual answer to this question is :
*for netbeans 8.2*

1. open netbeans
2. navigate to tools > options > java tab
3. in the Classpath text box, enter the path to the JDK folder of choice.

The path will be something along the lines of C:\program Files\Java......

The accepted answer is the process when you want to add a jar file to a specific project