# How do I add/import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool? Where is it located in Netbeans 7 / H2

Tags: java, netbeans, h2

I am developing a small application using Java 7 in Netbeans 7 and h2 database.Unable to resolve the following statement.

```
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;
```

The error stack is given below.

> Created dir: C:\Users\root\Desktop\ShopProject2\build\empty Compiling
>   26 source files to
>   C:\Users\root\Desktop\ShopProject2\build\web\WEB-INF\classes warning:
>   [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
>   C:\Users\root\Desktop\ShopProject2\src\java\dao\JdbcConnection.java:8:
>   error: package org.h2.jdbcx does not exist import
>   org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;
>   C:\Users\root\Desktop\ShopProject2\src\java\dao\JdbcConnection.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol    private static JdbcConnectionPool pool =
>   JdbcConnectionPool.create(url, username, password);   symbol:   class
>   JdbcConnectionPool   location: class JdbcConnection
>   C:\Users\root\Desktop\ShopProject2\src\java\dao\JdbcConnection.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol    private static JdbcConnectionPool pool =
>   JdbcConnectionPool.create(url, username, password);   symbol:
>   variable JdbcConnectionPool   location: class JdbcConnection Note:
>   Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 3 errors 1 warning

Can anyone please help? Many thanks in advance. Ram

Comment: Installed a plugin for H2 database engine support from Tools->Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Netbeans includes the JDBC Driver for H2 Database, but you can [download it from H2 Site](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html).

Also, see the [Question on how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans).