# Java package cannot find error

Tags: java, netbeans, package

As a first step, I tried to run a java project in my machine using net beans 7.2, (the instaled JDK version is 5.5). But I am getting some errors.

```
 D:\InterfaceSnmpMaster.java:17:     package org.snmp4j.smi does not exist
```

If I am right, I think I need to install something extra to get that package. Please help me....

Comment: Add `snmp4j.jar` to your `classpath`.

Comment: The version after Java 5.0 was Java 6. There was no JDK 5.5. I suggest you consider upgrading to Java 7 if you can.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - funny thing noticed :). +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use SNMP4J. Download the .jar from [their site](http://www.snmp4j.org/html/download.html), and add it to the [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) as explained in [How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

> ```
> - Right-click your Project.
> - Select Properties.
> - On the left-hand side click Libraries.
> - Under Compile tab - click Add Jar/Folder button.
> Or
> - Expand you Project.
> - Right-click Libraries.
> - Select Add Jar/Folder.
> ```