# package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist error

Tags: java, apache-poi, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a problem related to my adf application in jdeveloper 11g. When i build my application,i take these errors:

[image]

These errors in code-behind:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
```

I have investigated this error and i have learned that this error is related to apache poi. I have controlled my application and i have **poi-3.9-20121203.jar** file in my application folder :

> C:\roket1\ViewController\public_html\WEB-INF\lib

What can i do to get rid of these errors ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you haven't declared the path.

Comment: how does the path declare? sorry, i am beginner.

Comment: Your computer looks through a specific path of files and folders when it searches for things to import. Right now your computer can't find the items you want to import. You must update your PATH variable on your system to include the locations of your jars.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: It is oracle jdeveloper 11g release 1 (11.1.1.6.0) oracle ide : 11.1.1.6.38.61.92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JDeveloper then you can add libraries to your classpath with the following:

Add the JAR files you want to be in the classpath to the project's
libraries.
(Double click on a project to go to project settings - libraries- and
shuttle the correct libraries to the right , or add your own
libraries.

Comment: thank you. i have added jar files from Project Properties-->Libraries and Classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't constructed a path with the package you are willing to use inside your project.

Please refer to the following threads:

[How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

[How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

That should resolve the problem.

Comment: I think the question refers to JDeveloper 11g.