splitting of .csv file with header
Bellow is my java code. Which is for splitting of .csv files with header with a fixed number of rows.
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.util.Iterator;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class csv_split_with_hdr {  
public static void main(String args[])  {  
 try{  
  String inputfile = "C:/SUMIT/backup-old/SFDC/policy-extract/temp1/xxx.csv";
  System.out.println("Input Path is :- "+  inputfile);
  double nol = 2800.0; 
  File file = new File(inputfile);  
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
  int count = 0;  
      while (scanner.hasNextLine())   
       {  
        scanner.nextLine();  
        count++;  
       }  
      System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);     

       double temp = (count/nol);  
       int temp1=(int)temp;  
       int nof=0;  
         if(temp1==temp)  
          {  
           nof=temp1;  
          }  
         else  
          {  
           nof=temp1+1;  
          }  
      System.out.println("No. of files to be generated :"+nof); 

  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile); DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  String header;
  header = br.readLine();

        for (int j=1;j<=nof;j++)  
         {  
          String outputpath = "C:/SUMIT/backup-old/SFDC/policy-extract/temp1";
          String outputfile = "xxx"+j+".csv";     
          System.out.println(outputpath+outputfile);
          FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter(outputpath+outputfile);     

         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);
         out.write(header);
         out.newLine();
         for (int i=1;i<=nol;i++)  
          {  
           strLine = br.readLine();   
           if (strLine!= null)  
             {  
              out.write(strLine);   
              if(i!=nol)  
               {  
                out.newLine();  
               }  
             }  
          }  
          out.close();  
         }  

         in.close();  
    }
 catch (Exception e)  
 {  
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
 }  
}  
}

This code compiled and executed successfully when my system configuration was as follows
Processor : intel CORE i3, OS :- windows 7
java version :- "1.8.0_202"
java(TM) SE RUNTIME Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
java Hotspot(TM) client VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

But recently I chanced my system, and the system configuration is presently
Processor :  intel CORE 13, OS :- Windows 11
java version :- "22.0.1"  2024-04-16
java(TM) SE RUNTIME Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

But Now it is giving following error at the time of compilation through the command from cmd
C:\sumit\backup-old\SFDC\policy-extract\temp1>javac csv_split_with_hdr.java
csv_split_with_hdr.java:7: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
                                  ^
csv_split_with_hdr.java:8: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
                                  ^
csv_split_with_hdr.java:9: error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
                                ^
csv_split_with_hdr.java:10: error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
                                ^
                              
4 errors
C:\sumit\backup-old\SFDC\policy-extract\temp1>


Looks related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21064226/16034206

You probably need to upgrade your POI.

You don't need POI to parse CSV files. They are text files. You don't even need a specialised API if they are simple. Uncomplex CSV will be handled well enough by String::split. If you post a file sample we can advise ++ for using forward slashes in your WIndows paths though ;)

Files.lines(Path.of(inputFile)).count(); will get your number of lines

You still have import statements importing POI classes which you aren't using. Remove the import statements.

As said by others, remove the unnecessary import statements. Besides that, you should start using try-with-resources. Further, don’t include unnecessary artifacts in general. Besides importing classes you don’t use, wrapping the FileInputStream in a DataInputStream is unnecessary. You only need the FileInputStream and InputStreamReader (or use FileReader which combines these two in one step).

The problem is with how you build the program but you haven't enough details of that. You were using some libraries that you are not adding to the build explicitly. Probably a bad practice of putting them in some JDK directory. As others said if you don't use remove them.

Novelty answer, not completely tested and slightly hacky using java.util.stream.Gatherers. You need to compile thus: javac --enable-preview --release=22 CsvSplitter.java and run using (e.g.) java --enable-preview  CsvSplitter somefile.csv 20 with Java 22
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Gatherers;
import java.io.*;

public class CsvSplitter {
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void save(String header, List<String> lines, String partPath) {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of(partPath)))) {
            // Hacky! Do this better
            if (Integer.parseInt(partPath.replaceAll("\\D", "")) > 0) {
                out.println(header);
            }
            lines.forEach(line ->out.println(line));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = args[0];
        int numParts = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        // Convenience trumps 'efficiency' !
        int numLines = (int)Files.lines(Path.of(filePath)).count();
        String header = Files.lines(Path.of(filePath)).findFirst().get();
        int linesInEachPart = numLines / numParts;
        int numDigits = Math.max(1, 1 + (int)Math.log10(numParts));
        String partNameFormat = "%0" + numDigits + "d.csv";
        Stream<List<String>> partsStream = Files.lines(Path.of(filePath)).gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(linesInEachPart));
        partsStream.forEach(linesGroup ->CsvSplitter.save(header, linesGroup, partNameFormat.formatted(count.getAndIncrement()))); 
    }
}

