# java - how to compile a java file with Eclipse or NetBeans without errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, netbeans, compilation

I better explain the situation from the start. I wanted to change the resolution for a .jar file, so I decompiled it with [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/), then I went to Notepad++ and made a small edit, in 2 lines for a `.java` file:

```
    paramGraphics.setClip(0, 0, 176, 208);
```

to this:

```
    paramGraphics.setClip(0, 0, 320, 240);
```

And:

```
paramGraphics.setClip(0, 0, 176, 208);
```

to this:

```
paramGraphics.setClip(0, 0, 320, 240);
```

Then saved. After that, I wanted to compile that file to a class. I tried with javac command, didn't work and showed like 100 errors. It didn't compile. Ten used NetBeans. Same results, it didn't compile.

This is the compiler output in NetBeans:

`ant -f "C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\build\classes
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
  public Image jdField_int;
  symbol:   class Image
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  public a(InputStream paramInputStream)
  symbol:   class InputStream
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
  public void jdField_if(Graphics paramGraphics)
  symbol:   class Graphics
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
  public void a(Graphics paramGraphics)
  symbol:   class Graphics
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
      this.jdField_int = Image.createImage(this.jdField_do, 0, this.jdField_do.length);
  symbol:   variable Image
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      int k = j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] + 16;
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      int m = i + b.bF + 16;
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
      int n = i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] + 16;
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
      int i1 = e.jdField_if(m, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
      int i2 = e.jdField_if(n, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
        i3 = e.jdField_if(n, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
        i3 = e.jdField_if(m + 16, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
        i4 = e.jdField_if(m, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
        i4 = e.jdField_if(n - 16, k);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
      int i5 = e.jdField_if(m, k - 16);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
      int i6 = e.jdField_if(n, k - 16);
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
        paramGraphics.setClip(i, j, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else], this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - i7 - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF));
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + 16 + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 32 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + 16 + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 32 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + 16 + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 32 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + 16 + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 32 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i + (16 - (i + b.bF & 0xF)), j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 + (i + b.bF & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - 16 - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\src\javaapplication4\a.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
              paramGraphics.setClip(i, j + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] - (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) - i7, this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] - (i + b.bF + this.jdField_try[this.jdField_else] & 0xF), (j + b.bD + this.jdField_new[this.jdField_else] & 0xF) + i7);
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class a
31 errors
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:260: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)`

How can I recompile my file to class? I don't know a lot about java, so I'm a newbie in it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE!

This is the output log now...

```
    ant -f "C:\\Users\\USER\\Mis documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication5" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\build\classes
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\src\javaapplication5\Dun.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
      a.char = true;
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\src\javaapplication5\Dun.java:22: error: not a statement
      a.char = true;
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\src\javaapplication5\Dun.java:22: error: illegal start of expression
      a.char = true;
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\src\javaapplication5\Dun.java:22: error: ';' expected
      a.char = true;
4 errors
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\nbproject\build-impl.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\USER\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication5\nbproject\build-impl.xml:260: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Remove all the errors. Add all the dependencies.

Comment: You have to give all the dependencies to it, or it will be more clear to me when u post your errors there

Comment: I'm betting that all (most of) your errors are due to missing resources. At the very least, you need to give your `javac` command access to whatever other JARs and resources need to be available in order to build the thing. If your decompiler provides import names for you, those packages should give you a clue. That's a whole custom build, and it's outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @girishlalwani2010 I added the compiler output in the opening post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend compile your code with any IDE it will show you the errors and then accordingly add the required resources by that class and then try to run it.

Comment: Ok, I added the compiler output in the opening post.

Comment: @user1903782 these errors are clear that they shows various resources are missing thats why my friend this "cannot find symbol" error for various resources has been thrown by compiler like for ex: for "class Graphics location:" because you have not resolve the dependency for it by adding required jar to your classpath

Comment: @user1903782 download and add this jar to your classpath http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm

Comment: @user1903782 and please mark my answer as right by right clicking on it so it will be helpful for others

Comment: Ok this is what I did: Downloaded the file, and followed the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans. Tried to Clean & Build Project, but still errors are shown.

Comment: @girishlawani A little update, I understand now how this works, so I downloaded 2 more jar files to add them to the classpath. Now it only gives me 4 errors while compiling my whole project (not just one file). I added the updated output of this errors in the opening post. Thanks for your help! –

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all jars Y which the author used to compile the original class/jar X. Provided the jar X is self-sufficient (i.e. it does not depend on external jars like Y), then you can just add the original X to the classpath, then try to compile your modified class/jar X again (with your changes included). But almost no jar is self-sufficient these days so probably you will have no much luck. You just need to know all the dependencies which the author used at compile time for producing the jar X.