# IOException : spring-xml not found

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, exception

I am new to Spring and writing my first code. I am getting following error while running code:

```
Feb 09, 2014 1:21:23 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@64964f8e: startup date [Sun Feb 09 13:21:23 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 09, 2014 1:21:23 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I tried few combinations of moving spring.xml to different locations, same issue i found.
Here is the ss of my folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that resources is in our Classpath? It is not a maven project, so probably resources is not a Classpath root directory. The easiest way is to debug spring code internaly. In this case you'll able to know more about spring.

Comment: How to add resources to classpath

Comment: Following this link stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/…, i added the classpath to resources,still not working

Comment: above ss is the latest code

Answer (score 0):

Try copying spring XML to your com folder. It's searching for it in your current folder. If you are storing it in other folders then it should be on your class path and the path from root of of your project should be used while loading this file using ClasspathXmlApplicationContext. If resources folder is not in your Classpath then use  Example : /resources/spring.xml in your case.

Comment: I tried both , copying spring.xml to com folder and changing the path to resource/spring.xml. Still same errpr.

Comment: If spring.XML is in com folder then no need to specify /resources/spring.xml.

Comment: No , actually when it was in resource folder , i mentioned wirh /resource/spring.xml .. didnt work. Then i placed it in com folder with name just spring.xml... still didnt work

Comment: You have 2 choices 1) copy to com folder and specify spring.xml in your class 2) let it be in resources folder and specify /resources/spring.xml in your class

Comment: Could you please share your latest code and Classpath of your project

Comment: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AOPTest is the actual path. Following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans, i added the classpath to resources,still not  working

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that *resources folder* is in your classpth.
2. Change `spring.xml` name to `/spring.xml`. According [this example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html)  [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/2.5.6/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java) require slash before path. You should configure path as absolute, not as relative.