# Error creating an Excel file with Apache POI library.

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;  
import java.io.*;  


public class CreateNewPresentation  
{  
    public static void main(args[])  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            SlideShow slideShow = new SlideShow();  
            Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();  
            FileOutputStream out = new  
                FileOutputStream("slideshow.ppt");  
            slideShow.write(out);  
            System.out.println("File Created...");  
            out.close();  
        }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The issue is that it does not recognise `org.apache.poi` package.

How can I make it work?

Comment: where did you place your apache poi jar diles? What IDE are you using?

Comment: My jar files are here :- C:\Users\sony\.groovy\grapes\org.apache.poi\poi\jars . And I am running my script on cmd.

Comment: then you need to add -cp <poi jars> in your commandline argument else it will not find the required classes.

Comment: How can I do this in netbeans? and can you add the snapshot of cmd?

Comment: Sir, my jar file is here C:\Users\sony\.groovy\jars/poijar.jar . Now what command i have to enter exactly in cmd? can you please type here . My netbeans is showing some dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans) for setting classpath.
If you want to set classpath from command line refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Comment: Sir, my jar file is here C:\Users\sony\.groovy\jars/poijar.jar . Now what command i have to enter exactly in cmd? can you please type here . My netbeans is showing some dependency error.

Comment: Try java -cp C:\Users\sony\.groovy\jars/*" my.package.MainClass