# How to set image on jlabel from project folder?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am trying to make a Java desktop application.

I want to set an image on `JLabel`.

I am using NetBeans.

From my project folder, my directory structure is:

```
F:/>MARKET
    |
    |___src
    |
    |___lib
    |
    |___src
    |      |
    |      |__defaultpackage
    |                       |
    |                       demo.java
    |__images
            |
            |
            Logo1.png
```

I used following code:

```
jLabel4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/Logo1.png"));
```

It is not working, how can I get my output?

Comment: probably you write `Logo1.png` instead of `logo1.png`, check in your workspace

Comment: @Sarz thanks for edit  but  still i stuck with my prob

Comment: Is there any reason why there are two `src` directories?

Comment: @MadProgramer its autometiclly create in netbeans

Comment: By why are there two in your diagram?

Comment: Works for me. try `C:/Logo1.png`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the images included within the Jar, then you will need to move the `images` folder into the `src` directory.

This will then require you to use something more like...

```
jLabel4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Logo1.png")));
```

To the load image.

If you want the images to remain external to your program Jars (and remain open to the file system), then you need to ensure that the execution context for the program is within the context of the project folder (at the same level as the `src` and `images` directory).

This can be done via the Project Properties -> Run properties.  By default, when run, the program will execute from the context of the running projects folder.

[image: Properties]

If you're wanting to use external resources you can do two things to check for them...

One, create a `File` using the same path as the external resource you want to load and check to see if it exists...

```
 if (new File("images/Logo1.png").exists()) {...
```

Or if you can't seem to get it to work, check your current running context with...

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
```

Which will tell your current working directory (beware this will throw an `IOException`).

You can also use the system property `user.dir`

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you add images folder under build path?

if you use eclipse, add this folder to build path.
[image]

then you could find this picture in your code:

```
File file = new File("./images/test.png");
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans

Comment: it is about adding external jar file, not about load image @zhaorong

Comment: @Sarz, thank you, I see, however, if don't want to move image folder under src, add the folder to build path could solve this problem, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

try this by creating proper objects it give you clear image of processing and you can short your project later on. First try with `C:/`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Logo1.png"); 
JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
label.setIcon(icon); 
panel.add(label);
```