# Where is the java classpath in netbeans?

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces, themes

I'm developing a Java Web Application using Javaprimefaces. Now I have to insert a custom CSS theme. I'm following the tutorial at this [URL](http://primefaces.org/themes), but I don't know where to put the .jar file.

It says in the classpath, but where is it or how I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this question:

[How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

It is shown how to add a JAR to Netbeans' classpath

[image]

**UPDATE**

In case you were creating a Maven Project, you don't need to add the JARs manually to it. Instead, you should add the needed dependencies to your POM file. Check the "Installation / Maven dependencies" section of the tutorial you are following.

Comment: i know. i've already took a look at it but i can't find the libraries section.

Comment: Which version of Netbeans are you using? The Libraries section is in the Project Properties window, as you can see in the image I uploaded

Comment: maybe i'm doing it wrong. Right Click on my project->properties. I do it but it opens me a window like yours  without "Libraries" section...

Comment: Is your project a Java Web Application? Or what kind of project is it? I tried it with a Web App project and it worked to me

Comment: Maven->Web Application

Comment: You don't need to add the JARs manually to a Maven project. Instead, you should add the needed dependencies to your POM file. Check the "Installation / Maven dependencies" section of the tutorial you are following.

Comment: Did you finally get it? I updated my answer with the information above

Comment: sorry, i was AFK and i forgot to select your answer