# Java set up connection database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, netbeans, derby

I want to connect to a database on my computer. I have already created a database, but i cannot connect. I always get a classnotfoundexception. I don't know how to fix it. My database is called begindb and I want to use org.apache.jdbc.ClientDriver as driver. This is my code from my program:

```
private final static String JDBC_URL="jdbc:derby://localhost/begindb";
private final static String JDBC_DRIVER="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
private final static String USER_ID="test";
private final static String PASSW="test";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER_ID, PASSW)){
            System.out.println("good job!!");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So the first line in the try statement won't work. Because i am getting a classnotfoundexception.

Comment: Is the JDBC connector jar in your buildpath?

Comment: I don't know, i am trying this for the first time

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#configure_ns_client) Step 4 -

> To use the Derby Network Client JDBC driver, set your CLASSPATH to include the jar files listed below:
>
> derbyclient.jar: contains the JDBC driver
>
> derbytools.jar: optional, provides the ij tool

Add `derbyclient.jar` to your [project classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598688/2970947).

1. Expand you Project.
2. Right-click Libraries.
3. Select Add Jar/Folder.
4. Select "derbyclient.jar"

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. After i had done this i faced another prob with the connection, but if i added my port number to my JDBC_URL it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have derbyclient.jar set in the classpath to recognize the driver class (org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver) you are using.