# Get file from another package on different directory level

Tags: java, resources

This problem might have been answered before but I can't seem to make it work. Tried several different previously asked questions and answers.

I have an XML schema file in resource package, and need to get it as a File object from another package called ui.

It must the problem with setting relative path here, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

**Class pacakge:**
com/abc/ui/myClass.java

**Resource package:**
com/abc/resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd

**Sample Code:**

```
    File schemaFile = null;
    try {
        schemaFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd").getFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and/or

```
    File schemaFile = null;
    try {
        schemaFile = new File(getClass().getResource("../resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd").getFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

No matter what I try, it keeps throwing null value.

Update:
Snap Shots:
[image: Class View]

[image: Class Package List]

[image: Error View]

Any solutions to this.

Comment: `XMLSchema.xsd` != `Schema.xsd`

Comment: Sorry my typo mistake, corrected it. It wasn't a problem. I just tried to create a simple version of my code.

Comment: Have you added the resources folder to the build path?

Comment: @JamesFox: What do you mean by adding the folder to build path?
It is the part of a Project under source in Netbeans, its not a separate folder.

Comment: try `schemaFile = new File(getClass().getResource("XMLSchema.xsd").getPath());`

Comment: @MiteshPathak: nope still null :-(

Comment: don't use the ClassLoader, just type:
MyClass.class.getResource("../resource/XMLSchema.xml").getFile()

Comment: @BilalDja: `schemaFile = new File(getClass().getResource("../resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd").getFile());`

Still null

Comment: Check your spell..
public static void main(String[] args) {  
  System.out.println(new MyClass().fileExists("../resource/schema/XMLSchema.xml"));

 }

 private boolean fileExists(String url) {
  File XMLFile = new File(getClass().getResource(url).getFile());
  return XMLFile.exists();
 }

Comment: @BilalDja: unfortunately, still this is not working. I copied the path and used it but still no. Let me investigate more.

Comment: @indigo: How about adding a snap short of your workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of using resources, via the class, or via the class loader.

The class:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("/com/abc/resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd")
```

The class loader

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/abc/resources/schema/XMLSchema.xsd")
```

The difference is easy to see: the class loader uses absolute paths as it searches the class paths, several jars.

The class's getResource must start with a slash for absolute paths, and is relative to the package (directory) of the class. Because of inheritance `getClass()` might point to a child class package, so be careful there.

In your case try the more direct (jar limited) `getClass().getResource`. I would use an absolute path.

Comment: I don't why the relative path wasn't working but this solution worked pretty well. Strange, but happy to see this working.

Comment: I think that this would solve the issue with the relative path not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans