# Getting started with Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: classpath, stanford-nlp

I'm working in Java with the NetBeans IDE. I've downloaded the Stanford CoreNLP from their website and have no idea how to 'get it to work' in my Java project. I would like to be able to get this demo code working:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.CoreLabelTokenFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer;

public class TokenizerDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String arg : args) {
      // option #1: By sentence.
      DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(arg);
      for (List sentence : dp) {
        System.out.println(sentence);
      }
      // option #2: By token
      PTBTokenizer ptbt = new PTBTokenizer(new FileReader(arg),
              new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
      for (CoreLabel label; ptbt.hasNext(); ) {
        label = ptbt.next();
        System.out.println(label);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this. Off the bat, my import statements produce errors (can't find ___ package) Can someone provide step by step instructions for how to get this code to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you downloaded Stanford CoreNLP it came with a file `stanford-corenlp-<VERSION>.jar` and a `stanford-corenlp-<VERSION>-models.jar` that you should put on the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)#Supplying_as_application_argument).

This answer tells you how to do that with NetBeans: [How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)