# Recompile webapplication created in Java deployed on apache tomcat without the source java folder

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I have a web application on my apache tomcat webapps folder, and is running properly. But I need to make some changes on some of the java classes (compiled). I don't have the source folder on NetBeans. I only have the compiled classes and the .jar files.

How do I make changes on those classes and recompile them again?

Im using apache 7.0.63 and NetBeans 8.0.2 EE Edition.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Java de-compiler which you can decompile the class file you need to change and compile the changes using proper CLASSPATH.

Add the dependent jars in netbeans CLASSPATH, Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans) for more info

I use [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) for de-compilation.

**NOTE**: Since you don't have the source the licence of that application may restrict you from recompiling the source.