# added crytlib jar but still can't link to it

Tags: java

I added `crytlib.jar` to my `Crytest` project but when I run it.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   cryptlib.crypt.CreateContext(II)I     at
>   cryptlib.crypt.CreateContext(Native Method)

[image: picture1]

How can I fix this error?

---

#### Update 1:

This is my code:

```
try{     
    int context = cryptlib.crypt.CreateContext(cryptlib.crypt.UNUSED, cryptlib.crypt.ALGO_AES);
            cryptlib.crypt.Init();
            cryptlib.crypt.SetAttributeString(context, crypt.CTXINFO_KEYING_SALT, "abcxyz");
            cryptlib.crypt.SetAttributeString(context, crypt.CTXINFO_KEYING_VALUE, key, 0,key.length);
            cryptlib.crypt.Encrypt(context, ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);
            cryptlib.crypt.DestroyContext(context);  
            cryptlib.crypt.End();
        }catch(CryptException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You added it to the folder, did you also edited the build path?

Comment: @Nadir I don't understand. I always do the same with other project. Can give me more detail?

Comment: @Nadir I'm using Netbeans and I added library like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

Comment: Well, the error itself is caused when the jvm cannot find the appropiate native code to execute your java code. Does that library comes with native libraries (.dll, .so, etc.)?

Comment: It's from [this page](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/download.html). I already installed it to Ubuntu and the file jar in the `/binding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nadir alraedy guessed the `cryptlib.jar` itself does not contain any native code.

You need to download `http://www.cypherpunks.to/~peter/cl343_beta.zip` and unzip it. The Java binding is in `bindings/cryptlib.jar`.

To build the native code I believe you can follow the build instructions for Unix in the [manual](ftp://ftp.franken.de/pub/crypt/cryptlib/manual.pdf) on page 35.

> To build the shared library, use `make shared`.
>   Once cryptlib has been built, use `make testlib` to build the cryptlib self-test program
>   testlib, or `make stestlib` to build the shared-library self-test program stestlib. This
>   will run fairly extensive self-tests of cryptlib that you can run after you’ve built it to
>   make sure that everything is working OK.

**edit** Following a step-by-step instruction how to build a working library.

```
# download the archive http://www.cypherpunks.to/~peter/cl343_beta.zip
# extract the archive to any directory
# -a switch to ensure text files not extracted with DOS lineend
unzip -a cl343_beta.zip -d ${CL_HOME}/

# fix executable bits
chmod +x tools/mkhdr.sh

# re-generate the bindings
tools/mkhdr.sh

# modify some source files
# change in ${CL_HOME}/misc/config.h
   from  /* #define USE_JAVA */
   to    #define USE_JAVA
# change in ${CL_HOME}/bindings/java_jni.c
   from  #include <jni.h>
   to    #include "jni.h"

# copy JDK header files
cd ${CL_HOME}/bindings/
cp ${JAVA_HOME}/include/jni.h .
cp ${JAVA_HOME}/inlcude/linux/jni_md.h .

# build the library
cd ${CL_HOME}/
make
make shared
```

As test code I took the example from the manual.

```
import cryptlib.*;
class Cryptlib {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary( "cl" );
        try {
            crypt.Init();
            //Calls to cryptlib routines
            crypt.End();
        } catch(CryptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

copy library files into the directory of `Cryptlib.java`.

```
cd ${dir_of_Cryptlib.java}
cp ${CL_HOME}/bindings/cryptlib.jar .
cp ${CL_HOME}/libcl.so.3.4.3 .
ln -s libcl.so.3.4.3 libcl.so
```

compile the code

```
javac -cp cryptlib.jar Cryptlib.java
```

run the code

```
java -cp cryptlib.jar:. -Djava.library.path=`pwd` Cryptlib
```

There will be no output and no exception if the build was successful.

Comment: The problem is: I already done that before. But when I run `make testlib`. It returned `testlib.c:(.text.startup+0x11f): undefined reference to `fuzz'`

Comment: And I did copy the `cl343` to `/usr/lib` . But still error :(

Comment: I already did eveything in the manual. But still no luck and already run a command from `Terminal` :`java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/cl/ -jar ~/NetBeansProjects/Cryp/dist/Cryp.jar`

Comment: @Mr2uang Maybe some additional steps needs to be executed. Will have a look later and try to build the library by myself.

Comment: @Mr2uang Have a look at my updated answer. It has a step by step guide to build the library.

Comment: Do I need `dos2unix` because `unzip -a` already helped me. And `cp ${JAVA_HOME}/include/jni.h .` need destination bro!

Comment: @Mr2uang **1)** `dos2unix` is not needed as `unzip -a` converts the lineends as well, have updated my answer, **2)** in `cp ${JAVA_HOME}/include/jni.h .` the `.` means copy into the current directory (which is `${CL_HOME}/bindings/` after you did `cd ${CL_HOME}/bindings/`

Comment: Woow amazing but `make testlib` can't run bro!. Anyway why does `crytlib`  use so hard?

Comment: @Mr2uang **1)** Building the testlib wasn't the original question. Isn't it? **2)** Ask the author. ;-)

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=`pwd`` Cound you tel me What is `-Djava.library.path=`pwd`` and Should I call `System.loadLibrary( "cl" );` or not?

Comment: @Mr2uang **1)** The path in `-Djava.library.path` must point to the directory where the (file or softlink) `libcl.so` is located. As in the test all files where in the current directory the `pwd` returned the current directory. **2)** Yes you need to load the library with `System.loadLibrary("cl")` if you want to use it.