# Can't find a 3rd party library

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I'm doing some tests with Java EE and an Angular frontend.

I have almost everything ready to go, but I'm creating the backend, and needed the library json-simple, which simplifies the JSON parsing. I downloaded it, and imported the zip directly into my directory:

[image]

Ok, after this, I copy-pasted some code from an example webpage and tried importing the required sources:

> import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
>
> import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
>
> import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

Somehow, NetBeans can't find them. It just can't find the package "org", am I doing something wrong when importing these files? I tried importing only a folder with the sources, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: please unzip the library first, the library should be in jar format not jar.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jar

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/json-simple/json-simple-1.1.jar.zip

extract the zip and import the jar to your project. Set the classpath as below

[How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)