# Can't import a library

Tags: java, netbeans

A have folders test/labs/tryouts in E:....\exps
 and two .java files inside tryouts. The location is added into CLASSPATH: E:....\exps.

```
import test.labs.tryouts.*;
```

Doesn't work (it's hihlighted with red) and the use of described in .java files classes also fails:

```
Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Bullet
  location: class javaapplication1.Test1
at javaapplication1.Test1.main
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that these are `.java` files and not `.class` files?

Comment: This is unsolvable. Java does no "red highlights". What IDE do you use? Please read about minimal working sample in the guidelines on how to ask on SO.

Comment: @Pshemo added `.class` files into the folder, still nothing

Comment: @thst It's Netbeans. The red highlight says, there is no such a package.

Comment: Are you sure you've configured Netbeans with that Classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Most IDEs are using `-cp` or `-classpath` option to set classpath for each project which is

> preferred over setting the CLASSPATH environment variable because you can set it individually for each application without affecting other applications and without other applications modifying its value

Problem with it is that

> `-classpath` replaces the path or paths specified by the CLASSPATH environment variable while the tool runs: `java`, `jdb`, `javac`, `javah` and `jdeps`.

So try to add that path to your project rather than `CLASSPATH`. More info: [How to setup classpath in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)