# How to configure and install flamingo java swing ribbon button's and menus?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, radiance-flamingo

#### Problem:

I am new in Java swing flamingo framework. First of all, how do I configure it in netbean IDE, please guide me step by step.

I added flamingo 6.3.jar in netbean project, but it does not work or display the empty form.

[image: output Picture.png]

#### Script:

```
package javaapplication18;

//import java.awt.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.common.JCommandButton;
import org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.JRibbonBand;
import org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.JRibbonFrame;
import static org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.RibbonElementPriority.MEDIUM;
import static org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.RibbonElementPriority.TOP;
import org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.RibbonTask;
import org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.ribbon.resize.IconRibbonBandResizePolicy;

/**
 *
 * @author lubiesol
 */
public class MainFrame extends JRibbonFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                JRibbonBand band1 = new JRibbonBand("Hello", null);
                JRibbonBand band2 = new JRibbonBand("world!", null);
                band1.setResizePolicies((List) Arrays.asList(new IconRibbonBandResizePolicy(band1.getControlPanel())));
                band2.setResizePolicies((List) Arrays.asList(new IconRibbonBandResizePolicy(band1.getControlPanel())));

                RibbonTask task1 = new RibbonTask("One", band1);
                RibbonTask task2 = new RibbonTask("Two", band2);

                JCommandButton button1 = new JCommandButton("Square", null);
                JCommandButton button2 = new JCommandButton("Circle", null);
                JCommandButton button3 = new JCommandButton("Triangle", null);
                JCommandButton button4 = new JCommandButton("Star", null);
                band1.addCommandButton(button1, TOP);
                band1.addCommandButton(button2, MEDIUM);
                band1.addCommandButton(button3, MEDIUM);
                band1.addCommandButton(button4, MEDIUM);
            }
        });
    }

    private void add(RibbonTask task1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans ?

Comment: yes but not work

Comment: please help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

Author of Flamingo here. You're creating RibbonTask objects but not adding them to the JRibbonFrame's ribbon. See [here](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance/blob/master/docs/flamingo/flamingo.md) for complete Flamingo documentation.

Comment: Dear respected sir how we can import this code in netbean? please guide some @Kirill