# How can I add dbf.DbfReader to my java project?

Tags: java, netbeans, dbf

I am new to Java, but I need to understand how code written on Java works. There is `import org.jamel.dbf.DbfReader;`. I wanted to run the code on NetBeans, but I'm confused how to add this library to the project.

There is no `.jar` file and I've already tried adding the whole folder to libraries in my project, but it still does not work. I've downloaded the folder with the library from https://github.com/jamel/dbf . 
Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Would be very grateful.

Comment: You need to add the library to the class path of your Java project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans).

Comment: Do you have gradle installed to build the DbfReader jar?