# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver In netbeans

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect the database with Netbeans with the help of oracle 10g. I have downloaded odjbc7.jar file and added it in the ORACLE THIN driver in db services. Still, I'm  getting this class not found exception. (I am using Apache netbeans).

```
enter code here

       import java.sql.*;

        public class jdbclass {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
       {
             String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
             String uname="sh";
             String passwd="ara";
             String query="select pizza_type from pizza";
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname, passed);
             Statement st=con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
             String name=rs.getString("pizza_type");
             rs.next();
            System.out.print(name);
            st.close();
            con.close();

          }

        }
```

Comment: Have you set the jar in the classpath?

Comment: Please explain how you manage the dependencies of your project. Usually, we do not download the .jar; we include the dependency and the project management tool (Maven, Gradle, etc.) download it and include it on the path.

Comment: You probably already know this, but Oracle 10g has been [unsupported since 2013](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_10g)! Can you move to Oracle 12c?

Comment: @Aravind P - Any update?

Comment: Yes It works fine now .I have moved from apache netbeans to netbeans ide 8.2.With that I could easily add the jar file in the libraries.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use `ojdbc14.jar` as mentioned at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4721/beanh/index.html
2. Make sure you have added the jar in the classpath as mentioned at [How do I set the classpath in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-do-i-set-the-classpath-in-netbeans)

Comment: Yes..Thanks a lot.Now I've added the jar file in the classpath and it works fine now