# Stanford Parser - java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve as either class path, filename or URL

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I can not make Stanford Parser Version 3.5.1 work. I know that newer versions of this tool are available but I have tons of old code using this particular version. This is for an academic course.

I am using Windows 7, JDK 1.8.0_65, python 3.3.3 and NLTK 3.0.2

My environment variables are as follows:

- `CLASSPATH : C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\stanford-parser-3.5.1-models.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\stanford-parser-3.5.1-sources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\stanford-parser.jar`
- `JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin`
- `Path : C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\`

I run this code:

> from nltk.parse import stanford
>
> parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path='C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz')
>
> parser.raw_parse('I love apples')

And I am getting this error

> Loading parser from serialized file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz
>   ...
>
> java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz"
>   as either class path, filename or URL
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463)
>
> at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readStreamFromString(IOUtils.java:396)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromSerializedFile(LexicalizedParser.java:599)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:394)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:181)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedParser.java:1395)
>
> Loading parser from text file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz"
>   as either class path, filename or URL
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:463)
>
> at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:591)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromTextFile(LexicalizedParser.java:533)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:396)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:181)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedParser.java:1395)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:183)
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedParser.java:1395)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Zimtyth\Desktop\PFE\Implémentation\Codes\Code
>   final\Lib_Stanford_Parser.py", line 100, in 
>       resultat = parse_sent("My name is Melroy and i want to win.")   File "C:\Users\Zimtyth\Desktop\PFE\Implémentation\Codes\Code
>   final\Lib_Stanford_Parser.py", line 10, in parse_sent
>       return  parser.raw_parse(sent)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 152, in
>   raw_parse
>       return next(self.raw_parse_sents([sentence], verbose))   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 170, in
>   raw_parse_sents
>       return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 230, in
>   _execute
>       stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 161, in java
>       raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd)) OSError: Java command failed : ['C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp',
>   'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\stanford-parser.jar;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\jars\stanford-parser-3.5.1-models.jar',
>   'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser', '-model',
>   'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz',
>   '-sentences', 'newline', '-outputFormat', 'penn', '-encoding', 'utf8',
>   'c:\users\zimtyth\appdata\local\temp\tmpbf5zdg']

I have already checked a couple of answers in SO about this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912176/stanford-parser-java-error) but still I could not make it work. It looks like a Java problem, please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your code isn't right and you don't have any file at the location `'C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz'`.

If the models jar file is on your classpath, you should be able to get things to work by giving the model path (inside the jar file):

```
parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path='edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz')
```

The other choice is to expand the jar file (`jar -xf`) and then you would have an englishPCFG.ser.gz file, which you could as a parameter to the `model_path`.

p.s. For other people reading this in 2019+: You shouldn't actually be using this NLTK package at all any more, but rather: `nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPParser`