# Exception Description: Configuration error. Class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found at Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, netbeans

Firstly I read all post about that issue but I could not solve my problem. I have a web application with maven and I'm using glassfish & MySQL. When I want to receive info from database, I took this error. I will show you error:

[image]

That's my `.jsp` page I tried to take info from database:

```
<%@page import="tr.kasim.cc.app.Application"%>
<%@page import="tr.kasim.cc.model.SignUp"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"></link>
<title>User Listesi</title>
</head>

<body><center>
<p class="title">User Listesi</p>

<table style="border: black 1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td>loginName</td>
        <td>password</td>
        <td>eMail</td>
        <td>userName</td>
        <td>userDate</td>
        <td>userJob</td>
        <td>userTelephone</td>
        <td>userCity</td>
        <td>userGenderId</td>
    </tr>
    <%
        List<SignUp> users = Application.getApp().getMainService().getUsers();
        for (SignUp user : users) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=(user.getUserLoginName())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserPassword())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserEMail())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserName())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserDate())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserJob())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserTelephone())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserCity())%></td>
        <td><%=(user.getUserGenderId())%></td>
    </tr>
    <%}
    %>
</table>
<br/><br><br>
    <a href="index.jsp">Return HomePage</a><br>
</center></body>
</html>
```

And here my pom.xml dependency (I added dependency for mysql connection):

```
<groupId>tr.kasim</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseCenter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>CourseCenter</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Also I artifacted mysql to dependencies:
[mysql artifacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9tue.jpg).
I don't know what should I do. 
Please help me, thanks..

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819317/adding-dependencies-in-maven-netbeans

Comment: I explained that I added mysql connection . But it say mysql driver could not found. This is not same thing with my problem because "I added".

Comment: Why are you using version Connector/J 5.1.6 (released in 2008)? The latest version is 5.1.41 (released in February 2017).

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with Web Applications, you will need to remember one more point that the dependent libraries and jars should be available under `WEB-INF/lib` folder in order to let your Web/Application Server (Eg: GlassFish in your case, here) recognize them during runtime.

Copy the necessary dependent jars into the folder mentioned and redeploy to sort out your issues.

**(OR)**

You could do the below as well:
Just copy your `mysql-connector-java-5.1.x.jar` inside `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext`, even this will ensure that your problem is solved.

Comment: The OP is using Maven for libraries.

Comment: `lib/ext` is deprecated and has been removed in Java 9.